# Define method with arbitrary name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails application has an `ActiveRecord` model called `Game` which stores and relates information about a sport contest, including database items like `home_team_id` and `home_team_score` as well as methods like `winning_team_id` and `winning_team_score` which apply logic to the stored data.

I have another file in `app/models/` which defines an independent class `Record`. A `record` is created by passing as parameters an array of `games` and a `team_id` to create instance variables such as `@wins` and `@points_for` for the `team` corresponding to the `team_id`.

Within `Record` I to define two instance methods `average_points_for` and `average_points_against`, which does exactly what you'd expect:

```
class Record
    def games_played
        return @wins + @losses
    end
    def average_points_for
        return (@points_for.to_f / games_played).round(2)
    end
    def average_points_against
        return (@points_against.to_f / games_played).round(2)
    end
end
```

Seems non-DRY to declare `average_points_for` and `average_points_against` as two different methods. I realize I could do this...

```
class Record
    def games_played
        return @wins + @losses
    end
    def average_points(which)
        return eval("(@points_#{which}.to_f / games_played).round(2)")
    end
end
```

...but `average_points("for")` looks ugly — I prefer the convention of `average_points_for`.

What I'd prefer is something like this:

```
class Record
    def games_played
        return @wins + @losses
    end
    def average_points_#{which}
        return (@points_#{which}.to_f / games_played).round(2)
    end
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use `define_method` to define methods.

Comment: Note that in Ruby `return` is implicit and in every case here it can be omitted for brevity. Also note that `eval` is something you really, really, **really** want to avoid.

Comment: `method_missing` can also be used, but since there's only two variants on the method it'd probably be overkill. I think the best way it to leave it the way it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, for your use case it would be cleaner to just refactor it to DRY it up:

```
private def average(value)
  (value.to_f / games_played).round(2)
end

def average_points_for
  average(@points_for)
end

def average_points_against
  average(@points_against)
end
```

But, as comments indicate, you could use `define_method`. Rails does it to great benefit, as does Ruby itself in, say, `OpenStruct`; but it is an overkill in this case. If you really wanted to do it, this would be the way (untested, may contain bugs):

```
%i(for against).each do |which|
  define_method(:"average_points_#{which}") do
    (instance_variable_get(:"@points_#{which}").to_f / games_played).round(2)
  end
end
```

Comment: A working solution, but it'd be a lot cleaner if it was `@points = { for: 0, against: 0 }` instead.

Comment: @tadman: Oh yes, for sure. But sometimes you don't really have a choice (e.g. having `points_for` and `points_against` be ActiveRecord fields).